# Can implicit value be also a lazy value when used as implicit method parameter value?

Tags: scala

I have a test suite which uses Slick for DB access. Some tests in this suite access the DB and some not.
My suite has

`implicit val db = DB.getDB`

which effectively initializes `DataBaseDef` at the beginning of the suite execution. This value then is used as implicit parameter value for some methods.
Also it has the `afterAll()` which closes the `db` at the end of suite execution:

```
override def afterAll():Unit={
    db.close()
    super.afterAll()
  }
```

Now if I changed to:
`implicit lazy val db = DB.getDB`
then what exactly will happen?

If I run only a test which does not use the DB then the connection will not be initialized and in the `afterAll()` it will still try to close the connection and I have a problem in this case, right? I tried to run but no error happened and no exception was thrown...

My knowledge of implicits is not enough to help me understand it in combination with lazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> then what exactly will happen?

The value won't be initialized until the first access to it.

> it will still try to close the connection and I have a problem in this
>   case, right?

When you access `db.close()`, it will first initialize the value, which means it will call `DB.getDb` prior to closing the connection. This means, although you didn't intend to, the connection would be still initialized and then immediately closed, hence why you don't see an exception.

Comment: you are right. I thought more after posting the question and that became clear to me.
Still I would like to clarify the effect of `lazy` modifier on implicit parameter value discovery in methods invocation. Could you help with this?

Comment: or I can safely assume the standard rule: if nothing is told on this in specs than lazy has no effect in this regard?

Comment: @AlexanderArendar If you have an `implicit lazy val` that is required by a method which is being invoked, it will materialize the value. Meaning in your case it will create the DB connection.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the accepted answer, I'd like to point out that implicit are resolved at compile time, while `val` `lazy val` and `def` have implications at runtime only.

If you define an identifier as implicit, it will tell the **compiler** that you have access to an implicit value of the given type, so any method that need such an implicit parameter will use it; conversely, if you don't declare an implicit identifier of a given type, any call to a method needing a value of that type will throw a compiler error. However, once the code is compiled, there is no need for implicits anymore (they have been replaced by explicit references to the relevant identifier, depending on scope).

Now, at **runtime**, when an implicit identifier is called, it will be instantiated with the standard rules, so it can be either instantiated and memoized at definition if it's a `val`, instantiated and memoized at usage if it's a `lazy val` or instantiated at each usage if it's a `def`. The fact that it used to be an implicit parameter has no influence on the instantiation rules.

Comment: Thanks Cyrille for a useful and detailed clarification.